# Why do I get weblogic test connection pool error?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, weblogic, pool

When starting the weblogic server, I get the following problems:

```
 <Error> <JDBC> <BEA-001112> <Test "select count(*) from SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" set up for pool "jdbc/HIA_FLOWS" failed with exception: "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00903: nom de table non valide
".> 
 <Error> <JDBC> <BEA-001111> <Unable to verify the test "select count(*) from SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" set up for pool "jdbc/HIA_FLOWS". Connections will not be tested. The test will not be used by isValid either.>
```

In weblogic console I set the table test name to "SQL SELECT 1 FROM DUAL".

Comment: Which version of WebLogic Server are you using ?

Comment: weblogic 12.1.3

Comment: Oracle recommends to use SQL ISVALID from 12.1.3 for better performances.

Answer (score 1):

By your own words, you set the ***table** test name to "SQL SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"*. Given it generated a query `select count() from SELECT 1 FROM DUAL`, I guess you need to but in a **table name**, so set it to `DUAL` instead. Then I would assume it will generate a query `select count() from DUAL`.